# Is pressure from surface on cylinder = weight of cylinder when in water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

[image: 1]

Written here are net forces acting on a body. But I am having difficulty in understand them after reading from textbook and online material.

In the book, we have been introduced to thrust.

It clearly says that pressure exerted by a body on the surface = weight of the body.

Then, why is it not that $mg$ is nothing but $P_1A$ and $P_2A$?

Can we also say that it is $F = ma$ expression (the first equation as a whole) where $a = 0$?

Comment: Thrust has the units of force not pressure. Please recheck

Comment: @shahrozeshahab Please recheck my post.I

Comment: Weight of a body is equal to the difference of thrust P1A  and P2A ( thrust acting on the top and bottom respectively) only if its in equilibrium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It clearly says that pressure exerted by a body on the surface = weight of the body.

It is simply impossible — their units are different: $\left[N \over m^2\right]$ vs.  $[N]$.

Your book says something other - **thrust**, not pressure.

The picture is about forces and their difference. There are

- 2 forces in the top-to-down direction (the gravitational force and the force caused by the water pressure)
- 1 force in the down-to-top (the force caused by the water pressure).

So the first two forces are added together and the last force is subtracted from their sum.

The resulting force must be a zero force, because the cylinder is not moving.

Comment: Ok.I understood.I have also put the photo of what was there exactly in my book.I got very confused with that.Thank you for helping.

Comment: You're welcome. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Just one thing.how is it possible that my book has written wrong statement ?.That is a very big thing right

Comment: No, the statement in your book is correct — see my (edited answer), it is about **thrust**, not about pressure.

Comment: Oh.Ok thank you.